# Pillar jinja error on iteritems

Tags: python, linux, devops, salt-stack

Having issues iterations via pillar data and jinja template.  I took most of the template from a working salt/pillar installation but now failing to work in new environment.

I have tried several different syntaxes with the implementation of the iteration but still get same error.

ServerName:

### Data failed to compile:

```
Rendering SLS 'base:pillar_lab_user' failed: Jinja variable 'str object'
```

has no attribute 'iteritems'

```
Jinja Template

{% set users = salt['pillar.get']('XXXXXXX') %}
{% for user, args in users.iteritems() %}
{{ user }}:
  user.present:
    - fullname: {{ args.fullname }}
    - uid: {{ args.uid }}
    - gid_from_name: True
    - shell: {{ args.shell }}
{% if not args.empty_password == true %}
    - password: {{ args.password }}
{% else %}
    - empty_password: {{ args.empty_password }}
{% endif %}
{% if 'groups' in args %}
    - groups: {{ args['groups'] }}
{% endif %}


{% endfor %}
```

Pillar Data

```
users:
  user1:
    fullname: User1 Fullname
    uid: 951
    gid: 951
    shell: /bin/bash
    groups:
      - sudo
      - admin
    password: (REMOVED)
    pub_ssh_keys: (REMOVED)

  user2:
    fullname: User2 Fullname
    uid: 955
    gid: 955
    shell: /bin/bash
    groups:
     - sudo
     - admin
    password: (REMOVED)
    pub_ssh_keys: (REMOVED)
```

**{% for user, args in users.iteritems() %}**

What is the correct syntax for iteritems and accessing this data via a jinja template.
I have tried many variations of this syntax but still getting the

```
ServerName:
    Data failed to compile:
----------
     Rendering SLS 'base:pillar_lab_user' failed: Jinja variable 'str object'
```

has no attribute 'iteritems'

## EDIT

This was all user error, the pillar configuration was malformed. I removed the first line

```
"{% set users = salt['pillar.get']('XXXXXXX') %}"
```

so I didn't use pillar.get and targeted with pillar top.sls.  It works properly now.

Answer (score 0):

Your data should fail with :
`Rendering SLS 'base:so' failed: Jinja variable 'dict object' has no attribute 'empty_password'`

The reason why you see this error must be caused by non-existing pillar data.

You've pasted full pillar data but left `XXXXXXX` in state file.
It suggest that fix could possibly be as simple as:

```
{% set users = salt['pillar.get']('users') %}
```

or if it is not the case: check if you use `pillarenv`, then remember to pass the correct one, you can simply verify this in command line:

```
salt 'your minion' pillar.get users
```

If it doesn't return your dictionary then try:

```
salt 'your minion' pillar.get users pillarenv=your_pillar_env
```

Comment: XXXXXX is just to hide the real names of files.  Yeah, there is no empty_password field.  I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: I think so, however in your example you should have placed `salt['pillar.get']('users')`. Paste your salt-master config, what does the shell command: `salt 'your minion' pillar.get users` return? Do you use `pillarenv`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure @lakier is either right or headed in the right direction w.r.t. debugging your situation. It definitely sounds like `users` doesn't have a value when you call `iteritems()`. I'm not 100% sure, but your exception sounds like `users` is set to a string (i.e., Jinja variable 'str object') which makes sense because I think you get an empty string back when the pillar data you request doesn't exist.

Comment: This is all user error, the pillar configuration was malformed. i removed the first line "{% set users = salt['pillar.get']('XXXXXXX') %}" so I didn't use pillar.get and targeted with pillar top.sls.  It works properly now.